# Stored Procedure parameter inserting wrong value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, null

Good afternoon everyone,

I am having an issue with a stored procedure inserting an incorrect value. Below is a summarization of my stored procedure ...

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDifferential]
    @differential int = null
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            UPDATE
                DifferentialTable
            SET
                differential = @differential
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int, @ErrorState INT
        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
               @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
               @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH
```

Below is the code I use to call the stored procedure ...

```
SqlConnection dbEngine = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand dbCmd = new SqlCommand("InsertDifferential", dbEngine);
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCmd);

dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

if (myobject.differential.HasValue)
{ dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differential", myobject.differential); }
else
{ dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differential", DBNull.Value); }

dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In the database table, the differential column is a nullable int with no default value.

The differential property of "myobject" is an int? data type set to null by default.

The issue is when I run the stored procedure, the differential column winds up with a 0 in place. Even if "myobject.differential" is null and I pass in the DBNull.Value the column still winds up with a 0 in place. I've tried not passing the @differential into the stored procedure and it still sets the column to 0.

I've tried a number of different solutions and nothing has worked.

Thank you in advance for any assistance,

Scott Vercuski

Comment: Rather than a summarization of the stored procedure, can you provide the actual code? A problem like this is often the result of a single line of code somewhere, typos, etc.

Comment: Tom H. - Unfortunately my employer won't let me post the entire stored procedure for disclosure reasons, for that I'm sorry. What I can tell you is that the differential update is the only update in the stored procedure and the only place the differential is touched in this stored procedure.

Comment: It looks like you found your answer, but if you can't post the original code another option is to reproduce and confirm the error with the pared down version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you set the default value on a parameter like

```
@differential int = null
```

You do not need to add it to your SQL Command.

Try the code with just this and do not include the else...

```
if (myobject.differential.HasValue)
{ 
   dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differential", myobject.differential); 
}
```

Comment: RSolberg - This is one of the iterations I've tried in order to fix the issue, unfortunately it still didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Without being able to completely reproduce, I am just guessing.....  What is the value of the parameter before the command execute is called?  Is it 0 at that point?

Comment: RSolberg - actually that is something I haven't checked ... I know the VALUE being passed it is null but I haven't actually checked the parameter once it has been set, let me check and repost. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: RSolberg - I just ran the program and checked the debug info and the Value of dbCmd.Parameters["@differential"].Value is ""

Comment: What would you expect that value to be?

Comment: RSolberg - I would expect that to be passed in as null, if not I'm not sure what "" translates to in an integer sense, but my guess would be "" translates to NULL, I could be wrong, my SQL knowledge to this degree is limited.

Comment: RSolberg - Well hold the phone sir ... you are correct !!! I just ran this statement 'SELECT Convert(int, '')' and it came out with 0 as a result. Althought I don't know why DBNull.Value is passing in '' as a value from my code above.

Comment: RSolberg - Thank you !! I greatly appreciate your help! I'll be able to correct things with this info in hand.

Comment: @Scott: Great.  Best of luck, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certian that the differential column does not have a **Default Value Constraint** on it of zero?

Answer (score 0):

ALso check to see if there is a trigger on the table setting null values to zero.